# Python: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python-3.x

Every time I try to make an object of the Hall class via the Controller class, I get an attribute error. I know that I can create the object outside of the class, but within the class it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

```
    #entity
    class Hall:

        def __init__(self, name, location):
            self.name = name
            self.location = location

        @property
        def name(self):
            return self.name

        @property
        def location(self):
            return self.location

    #boundary
    class UI:

        def uInput():
            value1 = input('Enter name: ')
            value2 = input('Enter location: ')

            return value1, value2

    #controller
    class Controller:

        def add_hall_controller():
            value1, value2 = UI.uInput()
            hall = Hall(value1, value2)
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTjoE.png)

Comment: Please add the complete error message

Comment: Added as a picture

Answer (score 1):

Running the above code resulted in `Attribute error` because, the attribute you're attempting to change is actually a property that doesn't have a setter. And as far as i am able to understand, name and location aren't properties. Hence, you can remove `@property` decorator.

```
class Hall:
  def __init__(self, name, location):
    self.name = name
    self.location = location

  def name(self):
    return self.name

  def location(self):
    return self.location

#boundary
class UI:
  def uInput():
    value1 = input('Enter name: ')
    value2 = input('Enter location: ')
    return [value1, value2]

#controller
class Controller:
  def add_hall_controller():
    value1, value2 = UI.uInput()
    hall = Hall(value1, value2)

Controller.add_hall_controller()
```